# How to maintain the data across multiple pages in django?

Tags: python, django

I have webpage that takes the user input(software names),upon clicking on next button I am going to next page where I will take the user input again(ip,username,pwd) after clicking on submit I am going to a view function to process the data. But how I will get the data that is captured in page1 (softwares)?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).

But you can also use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to achieve your goal. The usage could be like:

```
def page_one_view(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        request.session['my_var'] = form.cleaned_data.get('my_var')
    ...

def page_two_view(request):
    ...
    if form2.is_valid():
        my_var = request.session.pop('my_var')
    ...
```

Also, as aIKid said, you could use database to store temporary data, but I don't think it is necessary to create separate model for temporary data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is comprehensive list of options for Django Passing data between views

[Django Passing data between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763115/django-passing-data-between-views)