# django: pass formset data into another view

Tags: python, django

My issue kind of build on this one post [How to pass data between django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787838/how-to-pass-data-between-django-views/32787887). I am trying to do a similar thing which is to use the data inputed in view 1 into view2.

However, the challenge is that with a formset, I need to be accessing multiple rows of data input and not just values. I don't know how to achieve this

here is what I have so far:
view 1:

```
def New_Sales(request):
    #context = {}
    form = modelformset_factory(historical_recent_data, fields=('Id', 'Date','Quantity', 'NetAmount', 'customer_name'))
    
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = form(queryset= historical_recent_data.objects.none())
        #blank_form = formset.empty_form
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = form(request.POST)
        #blank_form = formset.empty_form
        if formset.is_valid():
            request.session['sale'] = request.POST['sale']  
            
            
            
            
            
            for check_form in formset:
                check_form.save()
            
                quantity = check_form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
                id = check_form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
                update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnHand = F('StockOnHand') - quantity)
                update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(stock_reel = F('stock_reel') - quantity)
                
            
            
        
            return redirect('/dash22.html') 
    
  
    
    return render(request, 'new_sale.html', {'formset':formset})
```

and view 2:

```
def invoice_view(request):
    request = request.session.get('sale'))

#... i need to get each row of the formset from the above view

#and  I am stuck!!
```

I am hoping that someone would have a solution, I cannot find anything about this in django doc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I understand good your question but, I'll try to answer you.
You can do it with 2 different ways. One is send the values with a post in the frontend (HTML form or AJAX POST). If you wanna do it from the backend, you can add more args to the method and pass the values (or the entire formset), like:

```
def invoice_view(request, val1=None, val2=None):
    print(val1)
    request = request.session.get('sale'))
```

And then you can call it from the another view, like a normal function:

```
invoice_view(request, "asd", "asd2")
```

Comment: i see what you are doing there however I am such a noob I dont get how to pass form parameters for multiple rows as fonction parameters